# Set Oval throwing error

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception

I am currently working on a project, I get this error `Java.lang.NullPointerException`, I undrestand that this error happen when you try to refer to a null object instance, but what I do not know, is how I can fix it.

This is my code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(150, 150, 10, 10);
}

/** Main Method **/
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Run run = new Run();
    run.paint(null);
}
```

Please help me with a solution and also explain it, so that I learn it. Many thanks in advance. Andre

Comment: You are passing null here? `run.paint(null);`?

Comment: Well, if u know, then **why in the world are u passing `null`**?

Comment: If you read it properly you would see "but what I do not know, is how I can fix it."

Comment: Then provide us with the complete code so that we can pin point our answer (and use '@' to inform someone - see `help` while typing).

Comment: Just remove this line: `run.paint(null);`. You should call it using `repaint()` method if necessary: `run.repaint()`.

Comment: Usually you would not call `paint()`, which is a method that is called by the AWT Thread. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Azad you answered my question. Thank you man

Comment: Your main overall problem is that you're simply guessing at how to do graphics programming, and that never works. Don't guess, but rather go to the source, the tutorials (which Google will find for you in less than seconds), and read them through first before doing this stuff. Else you're in for a painful long slog.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah you so right, I actually don't know anything about graphics, thanks for the advice, many things I do with out actually knowing what they do.

Comment: Andre, you're in good company since **none** of us know anything about graphics programming when starting out, and to use them requires that we throw out a lot of assumptions, like trying to call some methods directly. This is where the tutorials will help you greatly. Use them. You won't regret doing this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah, I wish there was a like button here, its people like you that actually motivate me. Many thanks you just motivated me to actually learn it rather than doing it with out knowing anything. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You almost never call `paint` methods (including `paintComponent`) directly as this is what the JVM should be doing.
2. Don't override the `paint(Graphics g)` method of a JComponent or JComponent derived class such as a JPanel if you can avoid it. This method, paint, is responsible for not only painting the component but also its borders and its child components, and if not done carefully, overriding this method will not infrequently result in unwanted side effects.
3. Later when you want to do graphics animation, overriding `paint(Graphics g)` will result in jerky graphics since it does not do double buffering by default.
4. By overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method instead you fix these issues.
5. Don't forget to call the super's `paintComponent(g)` method in your override to erase any unwanted previously drawn images.
6. Read the Swing Graphics tutorials, both the basic and advanced tutorials. Links at the bottom.

---

Better code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyBetterCanvas extends JComponent {

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawOval(10, 10, 200, 200);
   }


   public static void main(String[] a) {
      MyBetterCanvas canvas = new MyBetterCanvas();
      canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
      JFrame window = new JFrame("My Better Canvas");
      window.getContentPane().add(canvas);      
      window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      window.pack();
      window.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

---

Better Still:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyBetterStillCanvas extends JComponent {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = 500;
   private static final int OVAL_X = 10;
   private static final int OVAL_Y = OVAL_X;
   private static final Paint BG_PAINT = new GradientPaint(0, 20,
         Color.black, 20, 0, Color.darkGray, true);

   private static final Paint FILL_PAINT = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
         Color.blue, 20, 20, Color.red, true);

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // to smooth out graphics
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      // let's draw something funky

      g2.setPaint(BG_PAINT);
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

      g2.setPaint(FILL_PAINT);
      // avoid use of "magic" numbers
      g.fillOval(OVAL_X, OVAL_Y, getWidth() - 2 * OVAL_X, getHeight() - 2
            * OVAL_Y);
   }

   // a cleaner way to set the preferred size of a component
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public static void main(String[] a) {
      JFrame window = new JFrame("My Better Canvas");
      window.getContentPane().add(new MyBetterStillCanvas());
      window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      window.pack();
      window.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

---

Tutorials:

- [Java Tutorials, Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)
- [Java Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- Basic Swing Graphics Tutorial: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- More Advanced Graphics Article: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, your really helping, I think am going to start from 0, that way I really undrestand what am doing, am going to read all java tutorials, I am young, so I have still a long future ahead, thank you so much again

Answer (score 5):

You may not pass null to your paint method! Here is a small example how to do it:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval (10, 10, 200, 200);  
    }
}

public class DrawOval {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing it the right way. In order to use graphics in java you need to build upon Swing/AWT components. Currently you are passing Graphics as null.

```
run.paint(null);
```

You need to implement this using JFrame and other swing components.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sending `null` to `paint`, `Graphics g` contains `null` (points to nowhere).

Then inside `paint(...)` you call `setColor(...)` on `g`, which is `null`. `null.setColor(...)` causes `NullPointerException`.